# Expo 49.0.20 -> 50: RNCWebViewNativeComponent.js: Could not find component config for native component

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-webview

I recently updated expo from v49.0.20 to v50 and I started receiving this error:

`RNCWebViewNativeComponent.js: Could not find component config for native component`

I can't figure out how to fix it. This is what I've tried:

- delete node_modules folder and reinstall them all
- ran an `expo install --fix`
- ran `expo prebuild --clean`
- delete pods folder and .lock file and reinstalled them
- ran `npx expo start -c` to clear cache

Nothing helped. Has anyone had the same issue?

Comment: Same issue. Looks like it's been reported here https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/3233